# Opening DMG Files in a new Finder window

Tags: macos, dmg

I have made a .dmg file for my application but,  when I open up my .dmg file it opens with the sidebar included. It most of the applications I have seen, the .dmg file opens up a new Finder window without the sidebar. How would I acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

You can control that by creating a .DS_Store - This is a "Directory Services" Store file, which is used by Finder to setup the position of the various icons in the folder, etc. The problem is, the format is very poorly documented. However, there is a workaround: Open up your to-be-in-DMG folder prior to packaging the DMG, make it so that the sidebar is hidden, and then create the DMG. When the DMG is created, it will contain the .DS_Store hiding the sidebar. You can see a bit more on this in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69467/consequences-of-deleting-ds-store

Comment: How do I make my sidebar disappear? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @AbhiUpadhyay I'm sure it's way too late but for completeness for future viewers, if you use the View -> Hide Sidebar menu option maybe that will work

Comment: @Technologeeks , can you please tell me how to remove the top toolbar from that new Finder window?

Comment: You can remove the toolbar with View -> Hide Toolbar

Comment: cmd-opt-S toggles the sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is just to pay for one of the utilities out there that builds disk images for you.

I use [dropdmg](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/), but there are plenty of others. (I'm not affiliated to any of them)